# Encryption of calls and files in XMPP

Tags: encryption, end-to-end-encryption, xmpp

I use Conversations, and my interlocutor is Monal (or another application for iOS (you can tell which is better)).

1. I plan to use [OMEMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMEMO) for encryption. Are files and photos encrypted or not?
2. Are calls encrypted only using TLS and how secure is this?
3. How can I check that everything is working correctly?
4. How can I improve call security if it is not sufficient?

If you can, please provide links to sources.